# Running tests against existing database using pytest-django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, pytest

Does anybody know how to run Django Tests using pytest-django against an existing (e.g. production) database?
 
I know that in general, this is not what unit tests are supposed to do, but in my case, I'm running the tests on Heroku. By default, Django creates a new test database, however, this is not possible on Heroku.

I found a solution that would work without pytest-django (`python manage.py test`): https://gist.github.com/gregsadetsky/5018173 
but as far as I understood, pytest-django doesn't make use of the test runner defined in the Django settings.

If anybody has another approach on how to run Django tests using pytest-django on Heroku (e.g. by automating a way to create the test database) I would be happy with that solution as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Following [the documentation](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#using-an-existing-external-database-for-tests) on how to link to an existing database:

> Using an existing, external database for tests
>
> This example shows how you can **connect to an existing database** and use it for your tests.
>  
>   This example is trivial, you just need to disable all of pytest-django and Django’s test database creation and point to the existing database. This is achieved by simply implementing a no-op django_db_setup fixture.
>
> Put this into `conftest.py`:
>
> ```
> import pytest
>
>
> @pytest.fixture(scope='session')
> def django_db_setup():
>     settings.DATABASES['default'] = {
>         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
>         'HOST': 'db.example.com',
>         'NAME': 'external_db',
>     }
> ```

Comment: Awesome! I don't know how I could miss that. It felt like I looked at the documentation 100 times.

Comment: This can happen :) @lmr2391

Comment: for those who are not able to make this work because of pytest.ini settings follow this https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/643

Comment: Where is the `settings` variable coming from? When I try this I'm getting a `NameError` because settings isn't defined.

Comment: @user3250386 `settings` refers to the Django project's `settings.py` file that is used to setup the application

Comment: @JohnMoutafis yeah I just wasn't clear on how it's being accessed from conftest.py. I didn't know if there's an implied `from django.conf import settings` that wasn't being included in the example, or if there was some configuration step with pytest-django I missed that makes it automatically available to `django_db_setup()`, or what. (Importing settings from django.conf was making the NameError go away, but still wasn't making the example work for me...turned out my issue was related to environment variables in a .env file and a completely different solution was needed.)

Comment: @JohnMoutafis actually, after some further progress, this did end up being relevant, and after sorting out my previous issue, adding `from django.conf import settings` did cause it to work.

Comment: @GlenVaughan yes that's the recommended way of importing the settings: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code (that's why it is no included on the example)

Answer (score 0):

For those for whom the solution above does not work. You can specify a different settings.py file in `pytest.ini`. Like:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = tests.settings
```

Then in the `new settings.py` file, import all the settings from the regular settings.py and override `DATABASES`:

```
from core.settings import *  # your usual settings

# Dadabase configuration for tests
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    }
}
```

In `tests.settings.py` you can also override other variables for testing and it will all be in one place.

I know that this won't allow you to take full advantage of the `pytest fixture` (such as setting the `scope`, and pointing to specific tests). But this is the best solution I found for specifying a custom database for tests.